# access swf text field through visual basic

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, flash

we have an .swf flash animation embedded into a visual basic application.

I am trying to read the contents of a text field in the animation called 'bob' using the following code;

```
TextBox1.Text = AxShockwaveFlash1.GetVariable("bob")
```

When executed the output in textbox1 is "_level0.bob" ???

This is different to the actual text in the animation, and idea how I can access it?

Have tried bob.text etc.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2):

Right found a solution that works with as3 and VB cobbled from a few other solutions, you need to use external interface in action script here is the code in AS3 and VB. Sends two strings hours and mins across.

AS3

```
function TimeUpdate(o:Object)
{
    var r:String = "";
    for (var v in o)
        //Move the values from visual basic to mins and hours

        if (v = "mins") mins = o[v];
        if (v = "hours") hours = o[v];

    time.text = hours + ":" + mins;

    return "TimeUpdate was called";
}

if (ExternalInterface.available)
   ExternalInterface.addCallback('TimeUpdate', TimeUpdate);
```

Visual Basic

```
Dim x As String
        x = "<invoke name=""TimeUpdate"" returntype=""xml"">"
        x = x & "<arguments>"
        x = x & "<object>"
        x = x & "<property id='hours'><string>2</string></property>"
        x = x & "<property id='mins'><string>33</string></property>"
        x = x & "</object>"
        x = x & "</arguments>"
        x = x & "</invoke>"

        Dim responce As String
        responce = AxShockwaveFlash1.CallFunction(x)
        MsgBox(responce )
```

hope this is of use to people.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have is twofold. First, you need to be able to know somehow that the swf is ready. I tried to get this to work in a VBA app once (Access), and I never could reliably get this to work.

The second thing you need to realize is that the TextField is of type TextField, not String.

Comment: Below are the action script variables;

Comment: Thanks Amy, that is prob why I can't access the text its self. Below are the action script variables; public var bob:TextField; public var count:Number; public var myTimer:Timer; I have been able to get and set properties of the textfield such as its x,y position (but not its text), but can't access the variable count at all without exceptions.

Comment: Right, looks like with as3 you can't access variables any more via VB flash player, probably a security related change.

Comment: Have you tried just reading the text into a separate variable in AS  and accessing that from VB?  My approach would have just been to call ExternalInterface from Flash when the text changes, which should do something or other on your AX control. It's been too long since I've dealt with it to remember what.